# Django {% url %} tag for the currently rendering view

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm developing a website that lets the user read books, displayed in different ways. For example, I have the following URLs:

- `/read_in_white/book_name/chapter_number` - Shows white pages
- `/read_in_pink/book_name/chapter_number` - Shows pink pages

  My view functions are `read_in_white(request, book_name, chapter_number)` and `read_in_pink(request, book_name, chapter_number)`

  At first I only had `read_in_white`, which showed white pages. It also had some paging controls in a Bootstrap navbar. These were all located in the `read_in_white.html` template, which included controls for navigating for a different book or chapter. For example, I had the following in the template:

  `<a href="{% url "app.views.read_in_white" book='Good Book' chapter=1 %}"/>`

  Now I want to add the `read_in_pink` view and template. The navigation part of `read_in_pink` will be almost identical to the one in `read_in_white`, with one difference:

  `<a href="{% url "app.views.read_in_pink" book='Good Book' chapter=1"/>`

  I want to move all the navigation to a base template, but I can't figure out what to put in the `(% url %}` tag. How do I find the current view's name? I know I can add it to the context, or I can change `book` and `chapter` to be query parameters so the URL is `/read_in_pink?book=...&chapter=...`, but I was hoping there was something as simple as `{% url this_view ... %}`.

  Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not, since that would introduce a <strike>very</strike> strong**er** coupling between view and template and that's usually a bad idea.

But this sounds like you want to parameterize the color, doesn't it?
Then you can pass the color to the navigation or wherever you want to.

```
def read_in_color(request, color, book, chapter):
    if color == "white":
        return render_to_response("whitetemplate")
    if color == "pink":
        return render_to_response("pinktemplate")
```

Then in your templates

```
{% url "app.views.read_in_color" color="pink" book="Good Book" chapter=1 %}
```

Comment: The color was just an example, the actual views show different parts of the text, in different layouts, with different additional data.

Comment: By the way, why would this introduce very strong coupling? It seems to me it would introduce just the necessary coupling - all views with paging will require templates with paging anyone. This way I'm just factoring the paging out of the templates.

Comment: I rephrased, it's stronger because now your template goes together with just a view object instead of only relying on data. It doesn't really inspire code reuse - however, it's just my beliefs, I have no scientific data to back it up with :)

Comment: Well, a template *always* goes with a view object - the view calling `render`. OK, this doesn't change the fact that it can't be done. I'll pass the view name in the context. I'm making the views class-based anyway, because they share a lot of code, I'll throw that into the base class, too.